# How to connect SpringBoot to multiple DataSource?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

While there are resources available (on both SO and outside) that suggest how we can include multiple data sources in a SpringBoot application, all such resources assume that we have **different entities** on the **different databases**.

I have a use-case where I have two databases that I need to connect from the same SpringBoot application:

1. The first DB (say primary) is for Live data and
2. The other one is for historic data (say data older than **90** days).

The only difference between the data in these two DBs is the corresponding date (say InsertedDate) on which the record was inserted/updated.

Now as the two DBs have the exact same schema, I don't want  to duplicate the corresponding entities and repositories in different packages just so that the two data source can scan different packages without any conflict.

If this is a SpringData JPA limitation, can someone suggest a better way to handle such scenario so that I can re-use my existing entity model?